# Terminal Password

Tags: command-line, password

For no reason, I am unable to put my password into the Terminal when trying to execute a command. My system is:

```
george_le_porge@desktop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:    22.10
Codename:   kinetic
george_le_porge@desktop:~$
```

The cursor just does not move.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The cursor doesn't move when typing passwords ... It's a privacy/security feature ... But it will read your typed password when you press Enter.

Comment: Thank you Raffa Spot on sorted. Wahoo!

Comment: Although, I now have this message. : https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification.

Comment: 'The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C

Comment: @George: That other one is an unrelated problem.

Comment: OK, thank you for the info Hua Ha. Appreciate.